# What is a word for a process that repeats at a consistent interval?

Tags: synonyms

What is a word for a process that repeats at some consistent interval or cadence? For example,

> We run the user testing _____ every week on Mondays.

Answer (score 1):

A process which repeats at set intervals is said to be **regular.**

> **regular** *adj*
>
> Arranged in or constituting a constant or definite pattern, especially with the same space between individual instances.
>
> – [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/regular)

In your sentence, an adverb (modifying *run*) is appropriate:

> We run the user testing regularly every week on Mondays.

However, you don't need both *regularly* and *every week on Mondays* because they each imply the same thing. "Regularly on Mondays" implies a weekly interval; "every week on Mondays" implies regularity. Because "user testing" is a noun phrase, you can omit the word you want entirely.

A better way of saying "every week on Mondays" might be simply "every Monday".

I don't believe there is a word which denotes an event which happens regularly. A *session* need not be regular. Even a *round* need not be conducted regularly — *round* suggests that a set series of tests is conducted, but not necessarily that those tests are done at particular intervals. A TV show might run as a serial in weekly episodes, or it might be an "occasional series" with no regular timeslot in the schedules.

In this case, English is flexible in allowing a word like *regular* to describe any number of different types of event.

Even if there was such a word, (let's say it's *flurble* for the sake of argument), the word implies regularity, so my comments about "every week on Mondays" apply:

> - We run the user testing flurble on Mondays — implies weekly regularity
> - We run the user testing flurble weekly — specifies the regular frequency but not exactly when
> - We run the user testing flurble every Monday — "every Monday" specifies the interval and even the day, so saying it's a flurble isn't needed at all.

I would use

> We run the user testing every Monday.

That sentence says what you do and how often it's done.

Comment: I'd say 'regularly' is the obvious and most appropriate answer. I wouldn't upvote though, as this is probably ELL level ... but I think the downvote is harsh and misleading. // The caveats about the polysemy of 'regular/ly' have tipped the balance; a qualified upvote. ////// ... ... Someone else has just upvoted too. Regular upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

> We run the user testing _____ every week on Mondays.

in that sentence, you do not need an adverb: "*every week [on Mondays]*" is an adverbial phrase indicating regular intervals.

*We run the user testing **continually***. = at regular intervals.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/continual) **continual**: recurring in steady usually rapid succession "*[The city had] a history of continual invasions.*"

(As opposed to "**continuously**" = constantly and without interruption:  [Merrian-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/continuous): **continuous** - marked by uninterrupted extension in space, time, or sequence. *The batteries provide enough power for up to five hours of continuous use.*)

Comment: I’d have finished your answer after saying that any adverb is superfluous. The continually thing is a red herring. But +1 for saying “don’t”.

Answer (score 0):

***round***

> a sequence of recurring routine or repetitive actions or events; a period of time that recurs in a fixed pattern ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/round))

or ***session***

> a period of time or meeting arranged for a particular activity ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/session))

So your sentence would be:

> We run the user testing ***round/session*** every week on Mondays.

But it is more idiomatic to say

> We run *the **weekly** user testing (**round/session***) on Mondays. (I would also suggest ***the weekly user test***)

***Session*** does not necessarily involve repetition, but I suggested it because it is [more often](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=testing%20round%2C%20testing%20session&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctesting%20round%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctesting%20session%3B%2Cc0) used with testing and besides, if you use ***weekly***, it cvers the connotation of *"repeats at some consistent interval or cadence"* that you are looking for.

***Weekly*** means

> happening once a week or every week:
>
> - The fire alarm has a weekly test/is tested weekly. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/weekly))

Comment: No problem with <b>session</b>, but you can say the same with less by eliminating the verb: we run (conduct) user testing every Monday.

Comment: Round or cycle sounds right.

Answer (score 0):

Periodic:

> We run the user testing *periodically*: every week on Mondays.